# tabledit with datatable jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, tabledit

I am having issues with following 2 plugins working together. I am sure I am missing something but for love of God I cant see it :-(

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#mytable').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': false,
      'searching'   : false,
      'ordering'    : false,
      'info'        : false,
      'autoWidth'   : false,
      'order'       : [[ 0, 'asc' ]],

    });

$('#mytable').Tabledit({
        url: 'update.php',
        columns: {
            identifier: [0, 'id'],
            editable: [[1, 'name'], [2, 'email']]
        }
    });

$('#edit-client').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': false,
      'searching'   : false,
      'ordering'    : false,
      'info'        : false,
      'autoWidth'   : false,
      'order'       : [[ 0, 'asc' ]],

    });

$('#edit-client').Tabledit({
        url: 'update.php',
        columns: {
            identifier: [0, 'id'],
            editable: [[1, 'name'], [2, 'email']]
        }
    });

});
```

As you can see I have 2 tables. One is called mytable and the other edit-client. Isuue Iam having is with second table. If i have one table(either one), everything is working fine. However , when i add second table, it wont work properly. Datatable works on both but Tabledit just on first one.Both tables are identical in both structure and data respectively.

Any help would be highly appreciated as iam stuck at the moment.

Thank you

Comment: please more details..about error...dont correct show yout tables ?..or what's your problem..!!

Comment: there is no error per se. Just when i have two tables with these plugins, second one doesn show tabledit plugin. One table works fine.
Settings for both as per above and both tables are identical, apart from their id

Comment: is only by the order you need first load the datatables and the your tabledit

Comment: first: $('#table1').DataTable(); ...$('#table2').DataTable();...next tabledit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check this:

```js
$('#example').DataTable();
$('#example2').DataTable();
$('#example').Tabledit({
  editButton: true,
  removeButton: false,
  columns: {
    identifier: [0, 'id'],
    editable: [[1, 'First Name'],[2, 'Last Name'],[3, 'Username', '{"1": "@mdo", "2": "@fat", "3": "@twitter"}']]
  }
});
$('#example2').Tabledit({
  editButton: true,
  removeButton: false,
  columns: {
    identifier: [0, 'id'],
    editable: [[1, 'First Name'],[2, 'Last Name'],[3, 'Username', '{"1": "@mdo", "2": "@fat", "3": "@twitter"}']]
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Creating-A-Live-Editable-Table-with-jQuery-Tabledit/jquery.tabledit.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
  <caption>
  Click the table cells to edit.
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br><br>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example2">
  <caption>
  Click the table cells to edit.
  </caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Username</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

First you need instance the datatable and next make this datatable editable..

Comment: awesome. This now works perfectly. Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

One other thing to put in place is to make sure your js `<script>` is before the `<body>` tag. It should only be loaded after table rendering